# Remove old version of deb package before installing

Tags: debian, dpkg

Is there a way to specify for the deb package that it must remove the old version of the package before installing the new one.

Suppose I have program_1.0.deb installed and I am making program_2.0.deb. How can I specify the the old version should be purged?

Replaces, Conflicts don't work, it just unpacks over current version leaving old files in place.

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean removing the old version as the user's pre-step of the installation like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/328021/763156) or you want your debian package do it automatically and internally when its installation is triggered?

Comment: @vahdet I want my debian package to do it automatically or force dpkg to do it when istallation is triggered

Comment: The old file should not be in place (but config file). If there are some files, it mean it was packed incorrectly. The new version install script should correct and delete old files.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi there was a file which was moved from root folder of application to its subfolder, but if I upgrade from old version, the file will be in root folder and subfolder. I want the one from root to be deleted

Comment: It should be a bug. Was the file was in package? or it was created by installation scripts of package? What it is in package (and correct package) is tracked, and so removed. You can force a purge of the package, but if file was not tracked, also `dpkg --purge` will not help.

Comment: BTW packages should be tested with `piuparts`, which checks for such stale file, so packages are easy upgradable/purgeable.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi It is custom made package. The old version knows about the file that should be removed but the new does not

Comment: It it was *in* package, it will be removed. If it was created later (e.g. in postinst), you need to delete it. Debian uses old and new information on upgrading. Check https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi It was in package, but it doesn't get removed on upgrade. I already tried it several times. I can remove it through postinst, but I wanted for It to be removed automatically by package manager or something like that

Comment: I understood this, but the question is: how it was installed on the system? By the `tar` in the package (tracked by package manager) or by postinst scripts (or at runtime). In that cases, it is the maintainer that should track them. [Use `mc` to navigate inside a `*.deb` to find how it was done in the old version, or with dpkg-dev]. We cannot answer, we do not know how the package was made. So you should explain better (and not the symptoms, we understood them).